# Add key to a selected keys set

Tags: java, selector, nio

I'm writing a NIO server and would like to response on a user request, i.e. write some data to a channel.

```
Selector selector;
//...
if(selector.selectNow() != 0){
    if(key.isReadable()){
        SocketChannel channel = key.channel();
        //read some data
        //respond
        key.interestOps(SelectionKey.OP_WRITE)
        //How to add the key to a selected set?
    }
}
```

After reading some data I want to respond. It means I need to add `OP_WRITE` to the key and then add the key to ***Selected-keys set*** and then write some content to a channel once the key appeared in a selected-set.

How to add the key to a selected set explicitly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't. From the Javadoc:

> Keys may not be added directly to the selected-key set.

You can only remove keys from it.

But you don't need any of this. If you want to write, just write, and *if and only if* the write returns zero, register the channel for OP_WRITE and return to the select loop. When and if the channel becomes writable, it will be added to the selected keys set automatically. You don't need to wait for OP_WRITE to do the initial write.

Comment: The issue is I do not quite understand who adds the keys the the selected set. For now it looks like some magic... Can you explain a bit? Is that on OS responsibility, not JVM?

Comment: Keys are added to the selected key set by the selector during `select()`, when the operations they are registered for become ready.

Comment: Yes, I was not quite correct in my question. I meant how does JVM detects that the channel is ready? Is it implementation/OS dependent?

Comment: The TCP stack in the operating system detects it. Specifically, a socket becomes readable when there is data or EOS in the socket receive buffer, and writable when there is *space* in the socket send buffer, which is almost always true.